# ThreeJS How to detect if any Box/Mesh collide with another?

Tags: javascript, 3d, shapes, pythreejs

I am really sorry if anyone already have asked this question, but I have tried to search a lot regarding this. **Is there any method** that can be use to **detect if one Box in Threejs is colliding with one or many other objects** in the scene?

```
let allObjects = getAllObjectsArray(); //returns all Boxes of the scene
let newBox = getNewBox(); //Adding new box;

let collidingObjs = allCollidingObjects(newBox);//I want a logic that will return array of all objects collide with "newBox"
console.log(collidingObjs)
```

Comment: You need to add a physics engine like [cannonJS](https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/) or [ammoJS](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/) if you dont want to do all the heavy lifting yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
function allCollidingObjects(mesh:Object3D) {
    let fromMeshes = getAllObjectsArray();//returns all Boxes of the scene
    let boundary = new Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
    let collidingObjs:Object3D[]=[];
    fromMeshes.forEach((meshNow:Object3D)=>
    {
        let otherBounds = new Box3().setFromObject(meshNow);
        if(boundary.intersectsBox(otherBounds))
        {
            collidingObjs.push(meshNow)
        }
    });
    return collidingObjs;
}
```

Very simple, working 100% fine. I don't know why no one is recommending this method.
By the way, thanks